# Input as check boxes is not showing validation error

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, simple-form

For some reason, when I tell simple form to present the input `as: :check_boxes` the validation does not appear.

I have tested the validation to make sure it is working in Rails Console:

```
irb(main):001:0> d = Document.create
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  ROLLBACK
=> #<Document id: nil, documents: nil, documents_cache: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, request_id: nil, data_to_other: nil, data_from_id: nil, data_type_id: nil, data_tos: []>
irb(main):002:0> d.errors.full_messages.each { |msg| puts msg }
Data type Please select a format.
Data from Please select a format.
Data tos Please select some formats!
=> ["Data type Please select a format.", "Data from Please select a format.", "Data tos Please select some formats!"]
```

I also verified that the validation I have is working by switching the input back to the default select menu and the error displays fine there. However, I would like users to select multiple inputs.

Here are some pieces to the puzzle:

**Model:**

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base   
  validates :data_tos, :presence => { :message => "Please select some formats!" } 
end
```

**Form View:**

```
<%= simple_form_for @document do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
      <%= f.input :data_tos, label: "To: ", collection: DataTo.order(:id),
        as: :check_boxes, value_method: :name,
        item_wrapper_class: 'checkbox-inline' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Controller:**

```
class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @document = Document.new
  end

  def create
    authorize Document
    @document = Document.new(document_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.save
        format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @document }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What's weird is that it does add the '*' letting the user know that the input field is required.

**Edit:** On other fields where the validation field is displayed, there is a class called `has-error` that is generated after submission. Not sure why the same is not happening on the `:check_boxes` field.

If anything is unclear or I need to provide more information please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the validations were working the entire time! The default for the field is an empty string, which 'presence' must consider valid.

My solution, for now, was to write a custom validation that checks to make sure the field is an array and that the size is not equal to one. If it is, then that must mean the user has not selected any values.

Comment: Follow up - you can turn off the default empty string with `:include_hidden => false`